# Folding bike for commuting and touring

Tags: commuting-bike, folding-bicycle, touring-bikes

When looking for a compact bike for storage and carrying reasons, a folding bike seems a great deal. But how do folding bikes perform for trips longer than 20km ?

---

I'm looking for a bike I would use for **commuting** with important traffic and frequent stops (Paris), together with **touring** (Europe). The bike has to be compact enough to be stored in a **small flat** and to be taken in **trains** and carried inside train stations.
Brompton bikes are known to be stable and robust. But due to the position of the rider and the size of the wheels, these folding bikes are never used for long trips (more often 30km, but also few 150km trips travelling between cities). Does it exists any kind of hybrid bikes which would combine both compactness and comfort with long distance ?

I've tried the [Grasshopper FX](http://www.hpvelotechnik.com/produkte/ghp/index_e.html) a foldable recumbent bike, which doesn't seem to be great for city commuting. How do 700c foldable bikes perform ?

Comment: These folks use Bromptons for touring: pathlesspedaled.com  It's all in the setup (they carry a bunch of really silly stuff, though.)

Comment: Bike Friday does have a whole line of bikes marketed as Touring (and are designed for centuries in mind as well as commuting), like the Bike Friday New World Tourist. For longer trips (traveling by flying and taking a multi day tour afterwards), another option is something built with S&S couplers, such as the Surly Trucker Deluxe, but this is more work than a simple folder. Certainly, if you want to ride for 150km, you want to avoid cheaper folders and go for the more premium stuff like Bike Friday or Brompton.

Comment: You may also be able to tweak an old Raleigh Twenty for 150 km trips - I've certainly heard of them being used for 50 mile trips before.

Comment: The "paratrooper" from http://www.montaguebikes.com/folding-mountain-bikes/ looks as though it should fold easily enough for daily use while still being able to do decent tours. The Airnimal Joey http://www.airnimalfoldingbikes.com/ likewise, I have a friend commuting ~30km/day on one but he doesn't tour.

Comment: Why would you use the paratrooper? These seem pretty bulky next to a bike friday or brompton (albeit cheaper), and the suspension fork and wheels seem excessively big. The Joey seems oddly sized versus Brompton/Bike Friday's offerings. Im also not sure about the paratrooper's rack, or the larger wheelsizes for these bikes or the disc brakes - they just seem excessively big and heavy (which is annoying when you have to take a bike on a train!). But the price is certainly better.

Comment: Because I've never seen someone fold a Friday in 30 seconds. If you're getting on and off trains when commuting I suspect quick and easy folding beats compact size. And the Ainimal compromises folded size for performance on the road. Yes, people ride Bromptons long distances, and race them, but those are "man bits dog" events specifically because the bike is not designed to do them.

Comment: The Friday Tikit folds in far less than 30 seconds - http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/bikes/folding/product/review-bike-friday-tikit-09-35207/
But it's a 16" wheel bike, like the Brompton. Probably more suitable for touring than a Brompton, but also more expensive.

Comment: How often do you need to take the bike on public transport?

Comment: Not much, let's say once a month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people do tour with Bromptons, so don't rule it out: [Touring on a Brompton](http://bikefix.co.uk/touring-brompton), [Brompton cross country touring](http://www.edinburghbicycle.com/blog/brompton-cross-country-touring-bike/), [The genius of Brompton touring](http://www.shanecycles.com/the-genius-of-brompton-touring/), [Brompton touring](https://stupidfatbastard.wordpress.com/category/cycle-touring/).

I don't know about France, but in the UK, not all trains allow large wheeled folders. If they do, something like a [Dahon Espresso](http://dahon.com/bikes/espresso-d24-2/) is a quick fold, but not very compact (folding handlebars help, and newer models have them as standard). The Dahon Cadenza is slightly less bulky, but slower to fold.

The [Jetstream](http://dahon.com/bikes/jetstream-p8-2/) is 20" wheels, doesn't fold as small as some other small wheel Dahons, but would cope with some sorts of touring better because of the suspension compensating for small wheels to some extent.

If you ever want to take the bike on a bus, you will almost certainly need a small wheel folder.

Another possibility is a Riese und Müller [Birdy](https://www.r-m.de/en/folding-bike/). They do get seriously expensive, but fold nearly as small as a Brompton (compared with a large wheeled folder; if your main use is commuting with public transport, the Brompton fold is enough smaller and neater to matter). (There is now longer a Birdy model specifically named "Tour", but they are still used for touring.)

(Photo below from http://www.pbase.com/image/83944065 is an older model Birdy.)

[image: Birdy with Icelandic scenery]

Comment: [Pacific Cycles](http://www.pacific-cycles.com/) might also be worth considering, but I don't have any experience of them.

Answer (score 4):

I found an old Dahon Boardwalk.  I seriously converted it for touring (love the upright position) by making my own front rack.  I added a rear rack and have changed gearing front and back to run nearly same size cog.

Bike has the ability to carry me and all gear(I weigh 90 kg) and has serious climbing capabilities.

I am in no hurry, and I'm a bit of a shutter bug so I pull a single wheel trailer too.  The trailer has a solar panel to charge camera, video camera, lights, phone, bike computer, tablet etc.

I dont subscribe to the usual hype and marketing on bikes because I have done many kilometres on this rig and will do many more.  It has proved itself.  Love the fact that its steel so easy to repair if needed.

Comment: Welcome to [Bicycles.se] @Ron. We recommend new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site, especially since it's different to how you're using it. In it's current form this doesn't answer the question, so I suggest editing to address the question more. See [answer]